# karate-core: why double back-slash escaping is not working while matching regex for array elements?

Tags: regex, karate

Based on karate documentation:

> Note that regex escaping has to be done with a double back-slash - for e.g: '`#regex a\\.dot`' will match 'a.dot'

matching numbers with `\\d+` is working fine for simple string variables:

```
* def foo = '123'
* match foo == '#regex\\d+'
```

but it's not working for string arrays:

```
* def bar = ['123']
* match bar == '#[] #regex\\d+'
```

> assertion failed: path: $[0], actual: '123', expected: '#regexd+', reason: regex match failed

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a bug: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/988

For now you can double the backslashes `'#[] #regex\\\\d+'`

But this will be fixed in the next version.

Answer (score 0):

Regex escaping has to be done with a double back-slash in Karate.
Related link: https://github.com/intuit/karate#fuzzy-matching

Sample Code:

```
* def bar = ['123']
* match bar == '#[] #regex\\\\d+'
```