# Why regex does not work in karate framework?

Tags: regex, api, frameworks, karate

I have a problem with regex in karate framework. I have a step:

`And match each response.games[*].Price.value == '#regex \'\\d*.\\d{2}\''`

All the time I get message :

*assertion failed: path: $[0], actual: '183.26', expected: '#regex '\d*.\d{2}'', reason: regex match failed*

Can anyone help me please? Where is the problem?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59241235/karate-core-why-double-back-slash-escaping-is-not-working-while-matching-regex

Comment: Thanks for help but it does not work. Message *reason: not an array or list*

Comment: Well, I meant that maybe the backslashes must be doubled. Ok, try `'#regex^[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]{2}$'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Double backslashes didn't work but your current solution works. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
'#regex^[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]{2}$'
```

Here, `#regex` is part of the syntax to enforce regex validation, and the rest is the pattern that matches

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9]*` - 0+ digits
- `[.]?` - an optional period
- `[0-9]{2}` - two digits
- `$` - end of string.